# How to subtract two Big Numbers

Tags: c++, math, integer-arithmetic

I am trying to subtract 2 very large ints / big nums, but I have run into an issue. My code works for subtractions like 123 - 94, 5 - 29 but I can't seem to get around edge cases. For example 13 - 15 should result in -2. But if I do `num1 - num2 - borrow + 10` on the first digit I get 8 and `borrow` becomes 1. Moving on to the last digit I end up with `1 - 1 - borrow(=1)` which leaves me with `-1` therefor my end result is `-18` instead of being `-2`.

Here is my code for the subtraction:

```
//Infint is the class for the very large number

Infint Infint::sub(Infint other)
{

    string result;

    Infint i1 = *this;
    Infint i2 = other;


    if (int(i1._numberstr.length() - i2._numberstr.length()) < 0)
    {
        Infint(result) = i2 - i1;
        result._numberstr.insert(result._numberstr.begin(), '-');
        return result;
    }

    else if (i1._numberstr.length() - i2._numberstr.length() > 0)
    {
        int diff = i1._numberstr.length() - i2._numberstr.length();
        for (int i = diff; i > 0 ; --i)
        {
            i2._numberstr.insert(i2._numberstr.begin(), '0');
        }
    }


    int borrow = 0;
    int i = i2._numberstr.length() - 1;
    for (; i >= 0 ; --i)
    {
        int sub = (i1._numberstr[i] - '0') - (i2._numberstr[i] - '0') - borrow;

        if (sub < 0)
        {
            sub += 10;
            borrow = 1;
        }

        else
            borrow = 0;

        result.insert(0, to_string(sub));
    }

    while (i > 0)
    {
        result.insert(result.begin(), i1._numberstr[i1._numberstr.length() - i]);
        --i;
    }

    int j = 0;
    while (result[j] == '0')
        j++;

    result.erase(0, j);

    if (borrow == 1)
        result.insert(result.begin(), '-');

    return Infint(result);
}
```

Would you kindly help me understand the errors or mistakes in logic I have made ?

Comment: `13 - 15` -- Why is this an "edge case" but `5 - 29` isn't an "edge case"?  Looks like you need to review your entire logic on paper first before writing any code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have done everything out on paper, my code works for anything except for example when I do 13 - 15, where I end up with 3 - 5 + 10 = 8, and then for the tens I get 1 - 1 - 1 = -1 so I end up with -18

Comment: Then you didn't do a thorough job "on paper".  My first comment was updated as to why one is an edge case, while the other isn't an edge case.  That just indicates you started to write code too early.  It is not a good idea to write code so early, and then hope that you can finagle with the partial solution by tweaking some code to get everything to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the 5 - 29 isn't because I can tell the num1.Length is smaller than num2.length and the Swap them around and then multiply by -1
Whereas for 13 - 15, they are both the same length.

Comment: Then  make the numbers the same size by adding leading zeros to the smaller number before subtracting.  Have you considered that?  Then if you did that, there would be no difference at all in how you subtracted the number, since the sizes would *always* be the same.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that's whay I have the two if else clauses at the start either to swap them around of to add extra '0's ... 
Ah okay to the smaller number okay I will update my code

Comment: The knowledge of whether the number is negative or positive shouldn't be known until at the last (most significant) digit.  That's why it is strange that two rather innocuous examples results in one being an "edge case" while the other isn't.  Again, this indicates something fundamentally wrong in how you've implemented this if two rather simple examples results in such wild differences in the final answer.

Comment: In calculating `13 - 15`, you calculated the units digit as `8` and the tens digit as `-1`. Shouldn't that result in `-18`? You wrote `-12`. `-18` makes sense in its own way, because `-10 + 8` is `-2`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yep thanks, updated post.

Comment: @Kai.G Forget about negative numbers for the moment.  Does your code work if the subtraction results in a positive number or 0?  If not, get that to work first.  Once you get that to work, then the issue is what to do once you get to the most significant digit and then to determine the sign of the final answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie such as 120 - 120 and 120 - 30 ? Then yes it does.

Comment: Not just those numbers.  What about 23 - 18, where you are forced to make borrowing to occur?  Or 101 - 89?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 23 - 18 works and so does 101 - 89

Comment: So what is the issue with the one you say is an "edge case"?  I think it's time to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and use your debugger, since if all of those examples you claim work, why this example is an "edge case"?  It contains borrowing, just like the examples you claim work correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie have been debugging on vscode for a while now x) Any moment I need to borrow (13 - 15) I add 10, as I borrow and that ruins the calculation. Because instead of having 0 - 1 = - 1; I get 0 - 1 = 9

Comment: Another thing you could do is test which number is bigger than the other, and always subtract the smaller number from the bigger number, remembering that the final sign will be negative.  So does you "big integer" class contain overloaded comparison operators, such as `<` and `==`?  If not, you should implement them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thats what I was going to do, but Im worried that comparing digits 1 by one would be slow ... Im not sure how I would optimise the comparison. But yes I have had that in mind for a while. 
And just add the negative sign at the end.

Comment: @Kai.G *but Im worried that comparing digits 1 by one would be slow ...* -- It will not be slow.  This is a simple loop that compares until one of the digits is not equal to the other, starting from the left-most digit (this is assuming that the size of the numbers are the same).  That takes hardly any time, even if the numbers are thousands of digits.  But regardless of that, your "big integer" class should have relational operators, otherwise it is not a complete "big integer" class.  At some point, equality and less-than should be implemented.

Comment: Or if the numbers are not the same size, compare the lengths.  The bigger number's length will always be larger than the smaller number.  If the lengths are the same, then a comparison as suggested in the previous comment can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you got `8` at the 1s position and `-1` at the 10s position. the sum of these two *is* `-10 + 8 = -2`, the correct answer (instead of `-10 - 8 = -18`, which is wrong).

EDIT: To systematically derive the correct answer, if you find the highest-digit difference to be negative, distribute the minus sign to all digits. Suppose the per-digit differences of two `n`-digit values are

a<sub>n-1</sub>, ..., a<sub>0</sub>

with a<sub>j</sub> be the difference at digit of 10<sup>j</sup>, and you find that a<sub>n-1</sub> < 0. Then total difference of the two numbers could be calculated as

-1 * (-a<sub>n-1</sub> * 10<sup>n-1</sup> + ... + -a<sub>0</sub>)

It should be fairly straight-forward to derive the correct (negative) answer by going through the sum from 10<sup>n-1</sup> down to 1s.